# [Emu8086]How to print a decimal number

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

- My program reads data from a file,counts the number of words and correctly increments a counter variable.

How can I print this counter variable which contains a decimal number.Which would be the best way.

This is the code:

```
      mov dx,offset counter
      mov ah,09h
      int 21h
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? When you say `counter` contains a decimal number do you mean a string representation of a decimal number, terminating in `$`? That's what that interrupt wants. What exactly is in `counter`?

Comment: in the counter there is a decimal number.example 10

Answer (score 0):

```
or counter,30h
```

and close the string
seems to be working fine

Comment: That will work if `counter` is less than 10 (decimal).

Comment: so you are saying if the counter is 11 it doesn't work.I will test it tomorrow ...

Comment: That is correct. If the counter is `11` (decimal) which is `Bh` then adding `30h` gives `3Bh` which is equivalent to `;`. So that's what you'll see. To display a bigger number, you need to divide/mod each decimal digit out and add `30h` to each decimal digit to make an ASCII digit. Form an array of those ending in `$`, then call your soft interrupt to print the string.